# Error installing Homebrew

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on my system with the command mentioned on their homepage

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

but it's giving me following error -

```
-e:67: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
-e:96: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
```

If I try to do cleanup, it says that it can't find brew command. I'm clueless here as to if I have it installed on my machine why can't I run any of the brew commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
xcode-select --install
rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like if you were to do an `ls -al /usr` you'd see that the local directory is `drwxrwxrwx` ... Have you tried `chmod 775 /usr/local` (that may or may not need `sudo` prepended).

Also, is brew installed in `/usr/local/bin/brew`?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: I do not see brew in that directory.
Also tried that chmod command too.

Comment: What does `which brew` return?

Comment: Nothing. No message after that.