# Error installing pg gem

Tags: macos, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, pg

In order to deploy my rails app to heroku, I made change to my Gemfile by adding

```
gem 'pg'
```

Once I did

```
bundle install
```

I am getting following error -

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1) 
Using i18n (0.6.9) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.2) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.38) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.1) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.3) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.1) 
Installing pg (0.17.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/aniruddhabarapatre1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.17.1/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I assumed I didn't had PostgreSQL installed on my computer and hence downloaded it to no use.
I tried couple of other options and ran following command with similar errors again.

```
gem install pg
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got this thing figured out.

Since I had PostgreSQL.app already installed. Gave following command -

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres93.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_config
```

Comment: In my case (with Postgres.app 9.3.2.0) the correct command was: gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin/pg_config

Comment: A variation of this worked for me. I had to run `env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config` - just be sure to match the correct PG version.

Comment: Update for Postgres.app 9.4 `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config`

Comment: it works here, but anybody could tell why to do this??

Answer (score 2):

This works => env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin/pg_config

Answer (score 1):

Do you have postgres development libraries?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

Comment: The canonical setup is ruby installed using rvm and postgress using the postgres.app or through homebrew. check the above link. also check out rvm if you continue to have problems.

Comment: I already enough issues with Homebrew. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532394/error-installing-homebrew]

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled then reinstalled postgresql.  Then I installed pg -v '0.17.1'.  After that I ran bundle.  It worked.